# Dynamic table with a checkbox per row and only one can be checked (true)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I know similar questions have been asked but no one helped me with my problem.

I am displaying a dynamic table with all result from a sql request and the user has to choose one row by checking a checkbox but ONLY one. The thing is I don't know how to do this with a dynamic table.

Could someone tell me what I did wrong or what could be improved
Here is my html and javascript :

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
   var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
      $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
    <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Position</th> 
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Select</th>
 </tr>
   </thead>
 
   <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in msg.payload">
 <td ng-repeat="item in row" >{{item}}</td>
 <td ><input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="row[1][]" /></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 
</table>
```

Comment: You're describing the use of a radio button, why not use it instead of checkbox?

Comment: When using radio buttons instead of checkboxes it doesn't matter if the table is dynamic; only one is allowed to be checked.

Comment: Ok well my bad I confused radio with a switch, thanks guys it wath that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change type="checkbox" by type="radio"